# C# Keys for WPF Calculator Pogram

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make some Keys for buttons, for example, when i press on the keyboard the number 2 in my program it need to run the same code that the click would have run.

My attempt:

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.D1:
            One_Click();
            break;

        case Key.D2:
            Two_Click();
            break;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to simulate clicks. You just need to run the same code that the click would have run.

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't know how to express myself, that's exactly what I want, I'll give an edit.

Comment: "_need to run the same code that the click would have run._" ...then run the code that the click would have run. There's no magic required, just run the code...

Comment: I think you have to make a button component, and call that method in that, I believe that what you trying to achieve. the above comments are saying to just run the program, you can use console text out-put to see some of your results

Comment: @MariusArion - So what are you asking us? You are clearly calling the code that the button click would call. It doesn't seem like you need help.

Comment: You'll need a keyboard listener to detect keyboard input whilst your app is in focus, then I'd recommend that you tie your keyboard input and your mouse clicks into the same code. If you're using MVVM style with Command Binding from the View then they would both link to the same function that the command maps to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create num buttons and call same methods for all the num button click and then you can write,

```
        private void btnNum_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          //Button btn = (Button)e.OriginalSource; //To get CommandParameter
          string DialedNum = (string)((Button)sender).Content;

          //Do whatever you want to do
        }
```